# Why won't heroku use my CSS file?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

Just trying to confirm a set-up for a RubyOnRails class (of which I know zero of either Ruby or Rails) and heroku won't play nice.

(Using Windows 7.)

The local Ruby/Rails/Sublime2/Git/Heroku set-up worked for a single html file with a single line of "H1" text to display. Like I said, - the - most - basic.

Next, instructor wanted to demo the location/use of CSS files in a Ruby project, so we're supposed to add a format some text:

Added  two lines of text, H2 and H3, and added these lines to the `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css` file the Ruby project frame generated:

```
h1 {color: blue; }
h2 {color: green;}
h3 {color: gray;}
```

Saved. Runs fine against the local rails test server at localhost:3000. Pretty colors.

Then

```
git status
    says (red) modified ..../application.css
git add app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
    says (in green) modified .../application.css
git commit -m "changed colors"
    says 1 file chg'd, 4 insertions(+), 5 deletions(-)
git push origin master (<- asked for a login)
    says it went to https://github.com/myaccount/myapp.git
    70c8100..cc2f6ac master -> master
git push heroku master
    (after a whole lot of using and removing)
    says http//:heroku-generated-name.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
To git@heroku.com:heroku-generated-name.git
70c8100..cc2f6ac master -> master
```

Yet the text displayed by my heroku-served app is all black.

Mind you, I'm getting a lot of different platforms at one time (git, heroku, Sublime, Ruby and Rails) but I thought I understood this much, at least from a couple of other exercises. The instructor looked it over, left it as an "exercise for the student", mostly because he's swamped by programming nobbs, not just programmers coming to new environments/languages.

Any help you can give is appreciated. Happy to supply logs, etc.

Back to rtfm again.

Comment: Is the stylesheet included in your layout?  Have you viewed source on your Heroku app to see if it's included properly?  Have you tried to access the CSS file directly on the Heroku site?  Have you cleared your cache to make sure it's not just re-using the old style?

Comment: How do I actually see what files are at the Heroku site, or their contents? I've only seen "clone to another app on your PC" which adds to the complexity of what's on my PC, while still leaving me suspicious of what's actually on Heroku.

Comment: View source on your page, find the CSS URL, go look at it.  Most browsers will let you look at the CSS as a resource in their developer tools so its even easier.

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain for you:

--

**Heroku**

Heroku is a "platform as a service", which means that it takes your `git` commits & pushes, and makes them work on its cloud infrastructure. It uses [AWS cloud hosting](https://www.heroku.com/policy/security#data_centers) to run the applications

When you mention you have "zero" experience in Ruby and Rails, to ease your mind about Heroku - it essentially takes a `git` push & `deploys` your application for you, with the power of the [Heroku buildpacks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks)

This might mean nothing to you, but don't fret!

Getting CSS to work is relatively simple:

--

**Rails**

Rails handles its css with something called the [`asset_pipeline`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html). This is designed to give you maximum control over your application's "assets" - the "static" files used to make your application more appealing to users

Typically, the `asset_pipeline` is contained within this folder: `#app/assets/`

This means that if you're looking to change any of the "assets" for your application, you literally just have to tap into the folders contained within `#app/assets`, edit them, and ensure they're being included in your `#app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` file:

```
#app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>

#app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
h1 {color: blue; }
h2 {color: green;}
h3 {color: gray;}
```

This should work in your development environment. Production is a little trickier

--

**Production**

Heroku requires you [*precompile*](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#how-to-use-the-asset-pipeline) your assets before pushing

This, again, is relatively simple:

```
$ rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

If you use this *before* pushing your `git` repo to `Heroku`, it will allow you to push the assets correctly

Comment: Done and done, no change. Started with complete logoffs and shutdown/reboot.

Comment: Done and done, no change. Edited the css file again, status showed file in red; 'add' file; status shows file now in green; commit -m ""; 1 file changed; push heroku master; appears to succeed; call heroku app: 4 lines of text displayed, all in black. Tried your 'rake'. It ran, but did 'push' again, and it says "Everything up-to-date".

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out last night, combination of rtfm, BSOD, and stackoverflow. Thanks to all for the help and hints.

Turns out that even with a standard install, which one would think expects html, css and javascript at a minimum (as well as ruby and rails) I still needed to mod the Gemfile, adding this line:
gem 'rails_12factor'

Weirdly, even after it's added, the heroku processing from a git 'push' still throws a warning that it's needed:

WARNING:

```
   Include 'rails_12factor' gem to enable all platform features
   See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-integration-gems for more information.
```

BUT now the .css file is recognized. Yeah.

And the BSOD showed me that the rails server reads the Gemfile only once, at start-up, and doesn't like it if I follow the heroku recommendation:

WARNING:

```
   You have not declared a Ruby version in your Gemfile.
   To set your Ruby version add this line to your Gemfile:
   ruby '2.0.0'
   # See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions for more information.
```

...since my local ruby is 1.9.3. When I changed this while the rails server was running, no probs. But after a BSOD (another prob to fix), the rails server start-up threw a ruby version mismatch error and never started.

Ah ha.

Fun with a new language.